# Results Change On Repeated Applications Of PyCluster's K-Medoids

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

```
import Pycluster as PC
matrix=([ 0.  ,  1.47,  2.43,  3.44,  1.08],
[ 1.47,  0.  ,  1.5 ,  2.39,  2.11],
[ 2.43,  1.5 ,  0.  ,  1.22,  2.69],
[ 3.44,  2.39,  1.22,  0.  ,  3.45],
[ 1.08,  2.11,  2.69,  3.45,  0.])
cluster,medoids,error=PC.kmedoids(matrix,3)
print(cluster)
```

i apply kmedoids on my distance matrix. when i print the cluster label of my data, it show a combination number within a list 25 times. Sometimes is 2,25,26. Sometimes is 2,64,66. For example: (Assume this is the statistic of one of the output)

```
2: 10 items

25:10 items

26:5 items
```

So, i wonder why the label number and number of item keep changing every time i run my program.

Answer (score 0):

K-medoids is a randomized algorithm, so you get different results every time.

The cluster number is probably the index of the medoid. Did you look at the source code of pycluster?